# Binding nested list using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to display an image and a name. The model I've created looks something like this:

[Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t749z.png)

```
class Controller {
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

class Car {
    public Media Media { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Media {
    public List<View> Views { get; set; }
}

class View {
    public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class OverviewViewModel {
    Controller Controller { get; private set; }

    OverviewViewModel(Controller controller) {
        Controller = controller;
    }
}
```

All classes implement INotifyPropertyChange.
What would be the best way to display the Car.Name and the first View.Thumbnail of the Views list for each Car in Cars?

I've looked at a DataGrid but wasn't able to figure out how to display the first Thumbnail. This might also not be the right way to create a grid, I haven't looked in the styling possibilities of a DataGrid yet.

At first I created a grid in the code behind file and displayed the information on load, but I want to be able to update the images from the model without the view knowing anything about the model.

**Edit:**

Apparently my binding was correct, I only needed to set the DataGridTemplateColumn like so:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Controller.Cars}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Media.Views[0].Thumbnail}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You've definitely got the right idea. Could you clarify a bit more as to what is confusing you? Have you tried using a simple `ItemsControl`?

Comment: @Jesse, 1. "update the images from the model", do you mean the properties of the model classes can be changed? Also, can collections (i.e. lists) be changed (items are added/removed)? 2. "I want to be able to update the images from the model without the view knowing anything about the model", would you like to have the parallel hierarchy of ViewModels?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am unable to show both `Car.Name` and `Car.Media.Views[0].Thumbnail`. I have tried an ItemsControl control but it still doesn't dsplay anything, I'm guessing I'm missing some properties or bindings but I don't know where to look.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov 1. The properties of the model can indeed change during runtime and new cars can also be added and removed. 2. I'm not sure what you mean by parallel hierarchy of ViewModels, could you explain this?

Comment: @Jesse, "parallel hierarchy of ViewModels" means that there is a `ViewModel` **for each** `Model`. For example, `Controller`< => `ControllerViewModel`, `Car` <=> `CarViewModel`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using a `ViewModel` and passing in the straight model. The task of the `ViewModel` is to have a special version of the model which is made especially for the `view` to which you want to attach it.

So you could create a `IEnumerable<NameThumbViewModel>` which can be easily bound to a datagrid, itemscontrol, etc.
So remember a `ViewModel` can be for a `control`, for whole `view` or even for a `row` in a `datagrid`.
And you can also have `ViewModel` who can contain `ViewModels` or lists of `ViewModel`.

So pass the `model` into your `viewmodel` and take care of the mapping back and forth because one of the true reason for `ViewModels` is to have a way to flatten down view related data in a easy consumable way.

Hope this helps

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I need to create a new property `IEnumerable<NameThumbViewModel>` in my existing OverviewViewModel with the NameThumbViewModel wrapping one `View` (from the model) which contains two properties: `Name` and `Thumbnail`. How do I fill this IEnumerable<> and update it when another `View` is added to the `Views` list in `Media`?

Comment: I'm not able to edit my comment. I've updated my question with the solution I came up with. However I'd still like to know why I should choose muliple ViewModels that wrap every Model over a ViewModel that wraps Multiple models like my example.